# How do I iterate through a pointer to a char array in C?

Tags: c, string, loops, for-loop

I'm new to C, and I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out the exact way to do this.

I need to iterate through a string and store each letter one at a time in order to decrypt it.

So what I'm doing is:

#1. Creating a place to store the string:

```
char toDecrypt[] = node->string;
```

#2. Starting the for loop:

```
for(int m=0; m< strlen(toDecrypt); ++m)
```

#3. Storing the char (to be decrypted later):

```
char i = toDecrypt[m];
```

So is the above valid, or should I be using a different notation to properly store the char?

EDIT:

Ok, I think I have that cleared up, so I just have one follow up question.

How do I check to see if a char is a "\"? My check doesn't seem to be working.

When I put

```
toDecrypt[m] != '\';
```

into an if statement, it doesn't work...

Comment: #2: you are evaluating the length of the string for each iteration in the 'for' loop -- I would rather use

`for (int m = 0, int L = strlen(toDecrypt); m < L; m++)`

Comment: Escape the backslash, `'\\'`.

Answer (score 1):

Define your variable as `char *toDecrypt = node->string;`

You will still be able to use `[]` notation to read/write it if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

This is [**wrong**](http://ideone.com/66pvPR): `char toDecrypt[] = node->string;`

You can resolve it in following ways:

```
char *toDecrypt = node->string;
```

or

```
char *toDecrypt=(char*) malloc (strlen(node->string)+1);
strcpy(toDecrypt,node->string);
```

Answer (score 0):

> - Creating a place to store the string:

You actually already have a place to store the string. `node->string` stores the string just fine. You can just create a pointer to point to it:

```
char *toDecrypt = node->string;
```

or if you want someplace to copy it you can make an array:

```
char toDecrypt[enough_space_for_the_string];

// or do it dynamically with:
//     char * toDecrypt = malloc(enough_space_for_the_string);
//     just don't forget to free() it later

strcpy(toDecrypt, node->string);
```

> - How do I check to see if a char is a "\"? My check doesn't seem to be working.

The backslash is an escape character in C so if you want to check for a backslash you need to use the correct [escape sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C):

```
toDecrypt[m] != '\\';
```